# Play Framework 2 recompiles all instead of one file

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Play Framework has a splendid auto-compile feature which I like very much. But our project contains like 1300 java files and anytime I change one of them and refresh the page in dev mode Play recompiles all of them instead of just one file. Should it be this way? Or is there a way to force play compile only really *new* files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the latest version of Play: 2.1.1-RC1

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/E_yLjyIpDMY/KUJCbMlLV2AJ

They state "Fixed some compilation problems on Windows". And it works in my case. Now it recompiles exactly one class instead of 10-20 previously.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. It still compiles everything. A bit faster though